# Python type inference and autocompletion inside map/filter/reduce with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm does a good job with method suggestions and autocompletion when it can infer the variable type, and when it can't I can usually add type hints to get autocompletion to work.  But I can't find a way to get PyCharm to infer the type inside map, filter, reduce.  Example:

```
l1 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
l2 = list(map(lambda s: s.capitalize(), l1))
```

Would really like to be able to type `s.` and have PyCharm popup suggestions.  Is there a way?  I know lambdas do not allow type hints.

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28130 (thumbs up near the issue title)

Comment: I can't believe that issue only have 13 upvotes. This should be something every pycharm user using type hints wants.